# 404 calling php files with axios in a ReactJS app

Tags: php, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am trying to dispatch an action with Reactjs and axios to an api created with php.

When using 'get', I do get the php file in plain text, but when calling the file with the 'post' method I get a 404 error.

The php file is in the same node project but in the api folder. I don't know if I need to create an express server parallel to my app.

Also tried to setup a local server with xampp and I get a 401, even adding the header to the php file where you allow access to everyone;
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

My code to dispatch the action:

```
   return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/auth.php', data).then(res => {
      const token = res.data.token;
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwtDecode(token)));
    });
```

I am new to a lot of these concepts so some help would be great. My possible solution would be continue testing the access to my xampp local server or try with an express server. This last one I am not sure if it can run php scripts.

But what I would like the most is to just call with axios the file in my project, and this is why I need help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Express does not run PHP files. You have to have an apache or other web server running on port 8000 to make this work.

Comment: I already have my node app listening to port 8000, and I would like to do it so;return axios.post('api/auth.php', data).then(res => {
      const token = res.data.token;
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwtDecode(token)));
    });  Can I run the apache server in the same port?

Comment: No you cannot. This is not going to work.

Comment: So I guess from your answer that I need to create a server to hold the API